# create sequence that refer to a table

Tags: sql

I want to create sequence  that refer to  a table ,
for example:

```
create table t1 (id int, name varchar (50))
create table t2 (id int, name varchar (50))
```

I want that t2.id will refer t1.id by default after I create that table.

Comment: Do you mean a foreign key, that references t1? Then t1 needs a key (either primary key, or unique constraint.)

Comment: Can you please elaborate on this " t2.id will refer t1.id by default after I create that table" and also tag RDBMS involved

Comment: hi ,i meant the t2.id will  populated with the last value of t1.id

Comment: So when a row is inserted into t1, you want another row automatically inserted into t2, with same id value? What about the name column? And what's the expected result if a t1 row is updated, or deleted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
alter table t2 alter column id int FOREIGN KEY(id) REFERENCES [t1] (id);
```